# How to let the application check a users input?

Tags: c#, winforms, random

I am making an Addition Tutoring sample, and I cannot finds ways to check for a user's input. I know there are ways where you could do a compare contrast on little things like, when a student's grade is 90-100, maybe you could apply a `MessageBox.Show` indicating that this student's grade is considered as an A in most cases. But, I cannot figure out which attempt to use when you are checking for an addition's sum. Like, the snippet below will generate new problems for a user to work on.

```
private void Newproblem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  Random Numbers = new Random();
  int number1;
  int number2;
  int Sum;

  number1 = Numbers.Next(400) + 101;
  number2 = Numbers.Next(400) + 101;
  theproblemLabel.Text = number1 + "  +  " + number2.ToString();
}
```

But I want to be able to check a user's answers as well. Will someone provide me an approach on how to make that happen? I will greatly appreciate any hints anyone could give me.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you are up to!? What Input do you want? Are you using a console-app, WinForms or WPF?

Comment: what exactly do you mean? do you want a way to see what the user filled in for the result of the sum number1 + number 2 ?

Comment: Oh, sorry, I am using Microsoft Visual Studio to do this.

Comment: @bash.d she's not using a console application, she's using TextBoxes. they dont exist in console apps

Comment: @Thousand This is not true! You can call a message-box from a console app very easily....

Comment: @bash.d yes, a message box maybe, but im pretty sure there is no way to use a Textbox or a Label in a console application

Comment: @bash.d Wy would someone use a console app to show a label and have a click event..

Comment: True, but I never claimed that ;)

Comment: Well, on my application form there is a problem label. (theproblemLabel) That one shows the addition problems generated for a user to work on. Then there will be a TextBox where a user could input their answer, but where there is an answer, there should always be a guide to check that answer. But I have no idea how to do that. Will someone give me a hint? This is homework, and I am new at programming. I will google something if you think the answer is too obvious, since I know I should be doing this myself but, I am stuck and the book does not have any reference to do this. Please help.

Comment: @Cindy: put all that information in your question, not buried in the comments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A better way would be to use a textbox for the question and another textbox for the answer.

Btw if you have used the properties before, you could use the property: `ReadOnly` and set it to true, so the user cannot modify the problem.

Layout with different situations:
[image: Not a number]
[image: Not correct]
[image: Correct]

Example:

```
//Declare variables so you can use them globally
int number1, number2, sum, userSolution;
Random numbers;

private void btnProblem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  numbers = new Random();
  number1 = numbers.Next(400) + 101;
  number2 = numbers.Next(400) + 101;

  sum = number1 + number2;
  txtProblem.Text = number1 + "  +  " + number2;
}

private void btnSolution_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  // You try to parse the text to a integer,
  // if it works its stored in userSolution,
  // If it fails, it shows the messagebox
  if (!int.TryParse(txtSolution.Text, out userSolution))
  {
    MessageBox.Show("Input is not a valid number.");
  }
  else
  {
    // Check user solution and compare it to the sum
    if (userSolution == sum)
    {
      MessageBox.Show("Correct!", "Problem Solved!");
    }
    else
    {
      MessageBox.Show("Not Correct.", "Please try again.");
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: @Cindy If you have any other problems, feel free to ask. I like these small exercises :P

Comment: Just for the sake of teaching. This solution introduce global variables where there is no need of them. Of course, here, they are not a problem, but it is better to avoid them when you can work differently.

Comment: @Steve Yes it isn't realy needed but you do have to use them here, atleast the sum, since you calculate the sum when creating a new problem, and that way the user can't change the solution if you would change the textbox input, or just put the textbox as read only to prevent this.

Answer (score 1):

You could store the answer in the Tag property of the textbox

```
number1 = Numbers.Next(400) + 101;
number2 = Numbers.Next(400) + 101;
int answer = number1 + number2;

theproblemLabel.Text = string.Format("{0} + {1}", number1, number2);
theproblemLabel.Tag = answer;
```

then, when the user clicks a button to confirm its answer, you check against the stored Tag

```
private void Answer_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  int userAnswer;
  if(!Int32.TryParse(txtAnswer.Text, out userAnswer))
    MessageBox.Show("Please enter a number!");
  else
  {
    if(userAnswer == Convert.ToInt32(theproblemLabel.Tag))
      MessageBox.Show("Correct answer!");
    else
      MessageBox.Show("Wrong answer, try againg!");
  }
}
```

I am supposing you have a TextBox called `txtAnswer` where the user types its answer and a button called `Answer` clicked to confirm the answer

Comment: How about proposing non-hack solutions? This kind of data should be stored in reasonable data structures, not stuffed into extra fields of UI controls.

Comment: @siride, because this is a pretty simple question?. Because there is no need to add an extra layer of complexity? Perhaps if the user asks how to store a bunch of questions and answers a better approach will be required, but, I think, at this stage let the solution be simple.